# Can't login MariaDB root user

Tags: mariadb, lamp

I'm trying to set up LAMP stack following this tutorial (without a raspberrypi): https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/6
After following thi step => GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURPASSWORD'; I can't login root user anymore, I don't know what's happening!

Comment: I assume the password is now `YOURPASSWORD`. Instructions that require a root user for wordpress site aren't a particularly well though out. Lets see if they respond to feedback.

Comment: Yes, it login with YOURPASSWORD thanks for helping! Now I need to change this password...